# Tooltip on disabled ContextMenu Item in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, tooltip

I need to show a Tooltip on some disabled ContextMenu items. I tried the workaround using borders and putting the Tooltip and menu item in the borders, but my menu design completely messes up, setting Margin, Padding and BorderThickness to 0 doesn't help.

Any ideas ? Another approach ? 

 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope you just want to show the context menu as disabled and non clickable that you can do by styling without making control disabled. Hence your normal tooltip will work.

Comment: Yes i want it to be disabled and non clickable, i have cases when the menu item is not disabled and i have cases when it is disabled, how can i achieve this with styling ?

Comment: see to make is non clickable you just have to set IsHitTestVisible=false and click wont work rest you can create style a style of button similar to disable state and apply it as and when required

Comment: Ok i tried it with IsHitTestVisible, it seems that the tooltip isn't working on IsHitTestVisible = false either, but it was worth trying, thanks.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I mean to say when you need to disable the button then make IsHitTestVisible=false, remember this removes mouse all events from buttons. In the case where you want the button to look like disabled but tooltip should be there then you can only change the style of button and make IsHitTestVisible=true. Let me know if you get my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it, thanks to **vinod8812**.
I gave my MenuItem a style with different VisualStates, then i just needed to change the VisualState of my MenuItem to "Disabled", the tooltip works fine.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(menutitem, "Disabled", true);
```

Not a perfect solution, but will work so far.

Comment: glad that it serves ur purpose